# How can I change the font size for a <h1> in react bootstrap col?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am importing a css file *(app.css)* to style the `<h1>` font. Here is what I have in my app.css file:

```
.h1 {
  font-size: 100px !important;
}
```

Here is the react bootstrap column I am trying to render. It renders on the page, but the font size of `h1` isn't changing.

```
import React from "react";
import "../App.css";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

function HowItWorks() {
  return (
    <Container className="text-center HowItWorks">
      <Row className="mt-5">
        <Col xs={12} md={4}>
          <h1>Create Account</h1>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default HowItWorks;
```

Comment: In your CSS file remove `.` before `h1`. It should look something like this: `h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
}`

Answer (score 3):

Try using an inline JSX  style object. Note the camel case:

```html
<h1 style={{ fontSize: "5rem" }}>Create Account</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a `.` before something, it is a class selector so the styles are applied for elements with the class `h1` rather than `h1` tags.

so your selector should be as follows for selecting `h1` elements

```
h1 {
  font-size: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ramesh! big help.